# CLLocationManager and unit testing

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, cllocation, ocunit

I have been trying to add some (logic) unit tests to my code recently. I've set up the tests with [Kiwi](https://github.com/allending/Kiwi), I like the BDD style and the syntax.

My problem now is that I'm trying to test some code that relies on `CLLocationManager` sending a correct `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`. However, this never happens when I run the test, presumably because `CLLocationManager` thinks it's not authorised. For the record, I have added a *.gpx* file to the test target and edited the scheme to use that file as the location (under **Edit Scheme...** -> **Test** -> **Info**). The same code works fine when I run the full app in the simulator. Any idea how I can get (simulated) location updates to be sent in a test case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dependency injection to specify the location manager you'd like to use. You can either:

- Specify it as an argument to the initializer (constructor injection)
- Set it as a property (setter injection)

Try to use constructor injection if you can.

Then for real use, pass in a real CLLocationManager. But for test use, provide a fake that you can trigger to send the desired method, with preset test arguments. This also makes your test deterministic by removing any reference to your actual location.

Comment: I was worried that was the only way, but that means I need to refactor the existing code quite a bit. The class that holds the CLLocationManager is a singleton, so if I want to use `initWithManager:` instead of just `init`, I can't use the `sharedController` class method to get an instance. Then, you're suggesting to create a mock `CLLocationManager`, intercept `startUpdatingLocation` and `stopUpdatingLocation` and somehow manually feed and array of `CLLocation` instances to `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`? What a pain...

Comment: This answer is correct, but as I point out below, I still decided to take a different approach for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Singletons are the bane of unit testing. There's another way. Expose it as a property for setter injection, but have your initializer set up a reasonable default — in this case, the desired singleton. Your tests can then replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going down a different way: I converted my logic test to an application test, so that the test actually runs alongside the app in the simulator. This has the definitive advantage that I don't have to jump through hoops to get `[NSBundle mainBundle]` and `CLLocationManager` to work exactly like in the app. I'd have preferred the conceptual cleanliness of a separate logic test, but I don't think it makes sense to rewrite code just for that.